# How to fade animate an image icon in html/css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Hi I am trying to duplicate the flame icon animations on the left and right of this wix webite:How can i position the flame icon to the far right or left and also make it have a fade animatiion

http://jirungu2012.wix.com/firebrandoption2

This is the htm code

```
 <section id="ourfires" class="portfolio page-section add-top add-bottom">
    <div id="right">
    <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/d57153_09c71d3fe10848c3a04b18f8d8a6c2b3.png_srz_p_487_587_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_png_srz" />
        <!-- inner-section : starts -->
        <section class="inner-section">

        <!-- container : starts -->
        <section class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <article class="col-md-12">
                    <h1 style="text-align:left;"><span class="animated" data-fx="bounceInRight">Our fire</span></h1>
                    <article id="article"><hr class="hr"></hr></article>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>



                    <div id="mid">

                    <p class="promod-text dark-text">Our fire is all about <b>Big Brand Ideas</b> that not only have an <b>edge in the market</b> and make a difference in the <b>bottom line</b>,but ieas are: </p>



                            <p>
                                <ul id="navlist" class="promod-text dark-text" >
                                    <li>Locally relevant</li>
                                    <li>Creatively imagined and executed</li>
                                    <li>Internationally recognized</li>
                                </ul>
                          </p>
                          <br><br><br><br><br> 
                  </div>

                </article>
            </div   
    ></section>
        <!-- container : ends -->
        </section>
        <!-- inner-section : ends -->
    </div>
    </section>
```

The css

```
#ourfires{

    background: url('../images/bg/03.jpg');
    background-color:#ffffff;


}
```

Comment: Add your code to your question please

Comment: @Magicprog.fr i have put the html

Comment: @JamieBarker kindly check the html

Comment: @Magicprog.fr  any help on the issue

Comment: @JamieBarker any help on the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on what I understood from your question.

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="right">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left, #right {
    max-width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
#left {
    left: 0;
    top: 40%;
}
#right {
    right: 0;
    top: 40%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#left").add("#right").fadeIn();
});
```

**[FIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/ktd98vjn/embedded/result/)**

**EDIT:**
I have used your code and compiled the required behavior in this **[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/z3HDM204ul).** Please have a look.

Comment: so what i undestand is that every section will have the div then the content inside

Comment: Yes, just to prevent the image from breaking.

Comment: I have edited the question and put the code for html however if i put the div right the inner content doent show

Comment: Your code contains `<hr class="hr"></hr>` which is wrong. `<hr>` is a blank tag and it doesn't need a closing tag. Then, why are you containing a `<ul>` in a `<p>` tag, use a `<div>` instead.

Comment: I have created a bootply for instance. **[Here](http://www.bootply.com/8SRVHmOFfh)** it is.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections one last thing I would like the image to be the background then the text on top of it.Not flame image then below text

Comment: See this: **[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/ZtZdrCQYxu)**. I've removed the `padding-right` and added negative `z-index` to the image.

Comment: Thanks Vibhor Dube I have added the code but the image is not showing as seen in this http://www.inspirodesigns.co.ke/job/firebrand/

Comment: i still cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: You have added the image in background. I can't figure out, what is actually bothering you?

Comment: yes i have added the image but the flame icon  is not appearing.As frm this http://www.inspirodesigns.co.ke/job/firebrand/ when you check the our fire section that is where i have put the background image.It is all blank.Kindly assist

Comment: kindly upload the  BOOTPLY again

Comment: Bootply is not working currently. Will upload the code elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add some Jquery animations after document is ready or window is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // animate your image
});


$(window).load(function() {
 // animate your image
});
```

Example of animation :[see this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve8e7m2p/1/)

[EDITED LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/ve8e7m2p/3/)

Comment: how can i make it be a background so that i can put text at the front

Comment: any help on the issue

Comment: See new link. do you mean somthing like that?

Comment: yes but then i want the flame icon to be on the background and outside the main container which is centered